# show that the mid-perpendicular segments AB and CD intersect at the bisector

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, triangles

The ABCDE pentagon has all angles of the same measure. How to show that the mid-perpendicular segments AB and CD intersect at the bisector of the angle DEA?
Is this pentagon regular or another? Maybe this problem has simple solution, but i don,t konow how to do it.

My attempts:

Let E be a cut point AB i CD. I've tried notice in triangles AEF and DEF, but im stuck.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I dont know how to start

Comment: Draw it and post your attempts.

Comment: Is this pentagon regular or another?

Comment: No. It's not necessary.

Comment: So I dont know how that pentagon looks.

Comment: I don't know stil how to solve this.

Comment: Show your attempts and you'll get a solution immediately.

Comment: Let E be a cut point AB i CD. I've tried notice in triangles AEF and DEF, but im stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be an intersection point of the mid-perpendiculars, $\measuredangle FAB=\measuredangle FBA=\alpha,$
$\measuredangle FCD=\measuredangle FDC=\beta$ and $\measuredangle FEA=x$.

Thus, by law of sines we obtain:
$$1=\frac{AF}{EF}\cdot\frac{BF}{AF}\cdot\frac{CF}{BF}\cdot\frac{DF}{CF}\cdot\frac{EF}{DF}=$$
$$=\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin(108^{\circ}-\alpha)}\cdot1\cdot\frac{\sin(108^{\circ}-\alpha)}{\sin(108^{\circ}-\beta)}\cdot1\cdot\frac{\sin(108^{\circ}-\beta)}{\sin(108^{\circ}-x)}=\frac{\sin{x}}{\sin(108^{\circ}-x)},$$
which gives $x=54^{\circ}$ and we are done!

Another way (L.Radzivilovski,R.Leker).

Let $AE\cap BC=\{P\}$ and $DE\cap BC=\{Q\}$.

Thus, inside bisectors from $P$ and $Q$ of $\Delta PQE$ are placed on mid-perpendiculars to segments $AB$ and $CD$ respectively.

Comment: Why  $108^o-\alpha$, did you assume this pentagon is regular?

Comment: @piteer No, but our pentagon has equal angles. A sum of them: $180^{\circ}(5-2)=540^{\circ}$ and from here any angle is equal to $108^{\circ}.$ The second solution is much more better. We obtain a proof immediately.

Comment: ok how did you use law of sines, why on the left side is 1?

Comment: ok thanks i see